# In Android, How to access a Google calendar Events?

Tags: android, calendar

I've created a Calendar Activity in my Android app. Right now, it accesses the calendar and events from the device the app is on using this code in my Calendar Utility Activity:

```
public class Calendar3Utility {
public static ArrayList<String> nameOfEvent = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> startDates = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> endDates = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();

public static ArrayList<String> readCalendarEvent(Context context) {
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
            .query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                    new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", 

"description",
                            "dtstart", "dtend", 

"eventLocation" }, null,
                    null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    // fetching calendars name
    String CNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];

    // fetching calendars id
    nameOfEvent.clear();
    startDates.clear();
    endDates.clear();
    descriptions.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++) {

        nameOfEvent.add(cursor.getString(1));
        startDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3))));
        endDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4))));
        descriptions.add(cursor.getString(2));
        CNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
        cursor.moveToNext();

    }
    return nameOfEvent;
}
```

What I want to be able to do is to have read only access to a Google Calendar that I control, so that all the users of the app can see the events of the online Google Calendar. can I use the above code and swap out `.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events")` for `.query(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/[another Google account I control]@gmail.com/private/full")` ? This isn't working at the moment, do I need to provide the password to the Google calendar or something? If so, how would that look in code? Thanks for the help.